# Divisibility and Lagrange Theorem

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, group-actions

I came across the following question from math olympiad:

> For $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, prove that $$n!\mid\prod_{k=1}^n(2^n-2^{k-1}).$$

While I can solve it using elementary number theory, I notice that $\prod_{k=1}^n(2^n-2^{k-1})$ is the order of the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ and $n!$ is the order of the symmetric group $S_n$.

So I was wondering can we view $S_n$ as a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ and invoke Lagrange theorem to solve the question, thank you so much.

Comment: HINT: look at permutation matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: Yes you can, and that is a very good idea. You can realize $S_n$ as a subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ for any field $K$ by making it permute the coordinates of size $n$ vectors.

Comment: Excellent observation, +1 from me: the magic words are *Permutation Matrix* as the others before me already hinted.